# Why is my Macos Menu Bar App not showing?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying the easiest thing in the book: create an applet for the top menu bar; some kind of status indicator. However, I've been through 3 tutorials and nothing does it: the app compiles but will not show anything in the menu bar. Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI 

@NSApplication
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        self.statusItem.button?.title = "TEST"
    }
}
```

As I said, nothing but the name of my App shows in the menu bar. And I still don't know how to get an output (I just need a print statement to work)

Comment: Are you actually running the app? You said it compiles, but didn't mention running it. Also, if you add a print statement to `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, does it get triggered?

Comment: I just press the "Run" button. Maybe I'm assuming too much. No, the print statement doesn't work either. The app seems to be running: it's in the dock and the top bar has the App's name.

Comment: Which Xcode template and options did you choose?

Comment: Xcode v13.4 downloaded from apple website (due to size and slower downloads in the Store). I clicked File > New > Project > macOS (tab) > App > SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

For a minimal reproducible Menu Bar App in Swift:

```
import SwiftUI 

@main
struct <your-app>: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        Settings {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    static pricate(set) var instance: AppDelegate!
    lazy var statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)

    // Define your menu here (out of scope for this question)
    // let menu = ApplicationMenu()    <-- define ApplicationMenu() 

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        AppDelegate.instance = self 
        
        // Define the Menu Bar Icon as Text 
        statusBarItem.button?.title = "hello world"

        // Enable your Menu (out of scope)
        // statusBarItem.menu = menu.createMenu()    <-- define createMenu()
    }
}
```

Compile and Run, you should see a nice little *'hello world'* next to your battery status icon.

**Out of Scope**
To add a menu to this MacOs Top Bar Applet app you'll need a new `ApplicationMenu` class with a `createMenu()` function.